# Sitecore: ADC full text query to search for GUID

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

```
SearchParam searchParam = new SearchParam();
        searchParam.Database = Fields.Database;
        searchParam.Language = Fields.Language;
        searchParam.TemplateIds = templateID;
        if (txtQuery != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQuery))
            searchParam.FullTextQuery = txtQuery;
        QueryRunner runner = new QueryRunner("Web");
        IEnumerable<SkinnyItem> items = runner.GetItems(searchParam, sc.Search.QueryOccurance.Should, false, "", true, 0, 500);
```

I wan to make a search for a field that contain certain GUID, is it possible?
I have tried it, but it returns result of 0 where I'm sure that there will be result.
Am I missing sth or do I need to format the GUID format?
This is the format I used "{xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your index is setup correct to include the fields you are searching for and that you are using the correct query syntax.
See [this page](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/using-the-sitecore-open-source-advanceddatabasecrawler-lucene-indexer/) on how to configure your index and how to do simple and advanced searches.

Also try a hardcoded query to make sure you are not using wrong values somewhere or wrong formatting.

Comment: Thanks, the reference u have attached very useful for querying multiple GUID..~

Answer (score 1):

You're question is unclear so I'm going to interpret here. You say you want to do a full text search for a GUID. Those are naturally two separate things. I assume you have a GUID and want to find all items in the index that have that GUID assigned via some (any?) field. You'll want to use the `RelatedIds` property of the `SearchParam` ([code here](https://github.com/sitecorian/SitecoreSearchContrib/blob/master/scSearchContrib.Searcher/Parameters/SearchParam.cs)) for this:

Here's some sample code:

```
var searchParam = new SearchParam
{
  Database = Sitecore.Context.Database.Name,
  Language = Sitecore.Context.Language.Name,
  RelatedIds = {YOUR GUID HERE}
};

using (var runner = new QueryRunner(indexName))
{
  return runner.GetItems(searchParam);
}
```

Also, if you have more than one GUID, you can pipe-delimit them, e.g. `RelatedIds = {GUID1}|{GUID2}`

Comment: I agree with you on this Mark. You can pipeline the Guids to search.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what is in the index, you can check the field values stored using Sitecore Rocks ->

Right Click Your site,  Manage, Indexes, {Your Index}.

Check one of the guid fields to see whats in there.

I think they are stored without the curly brackets, hyphens and in lower case, you'd just need to format the guid before passing it in.

Comment: when i try to view those value in raw value mode, it shows {xxx}|{xxx}|{xxx} 
i think I need to configure the crawler.config to include for GUID search ..~

Comment: Its not in the content tree you need to be looking, its how the guids are stored in the lucene index that matters. If you post your config file I can take a look.

Comment: @user2035730: You have to update the crawler to search for that template/ID to search. If it is not present in the index crawler then the search will not result anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search on field value then you should use the FieldSearchParam instead of SearchParam. Here is the sample code:

```
    var searchParam = new FieldSearchParam
        {
            Database = Sitecore.Context.Database.Name,
            Language = Sitecore.Context.Language.Name,
            TemplateIds = DealerTemplateId,
            FieldName = <FieldName>,
            FieldValue = <FieldValue>
        };

        QueryRunner runner = new QueryRunner("Web");
    IEnumerable<SkinnyItem> items = runner.GetItems(searchParam);
```

This FieldSearchParam, is extended from SearchParam in ["Sitecore.SharedSource.Searcher"](http://www.sitecoredevelopment.com/en/Categories/Shared-Source-Library.aspx) library. This in open source, you can either add reference or get code in your project.

One thing to note here is the format of FieldValue, your field value should all be in small and without "-", so if your GUID is "{A9294EF5-0E36-4616-A77E-B7B100057EBA}" then you should pass ""a9294ef50e364616a77eb7b100057eba" i.e. no "{}" and all characters should be in small.
Try this, as this worked for me.

Note: Please ensure you have checked the configuration as per suggestion from @martijn

Comment: I have tried this out, with or without the GUID format, it is still working fine. 
But when I want to search multiple GUID {xxx-xxx}|{xxx-xxx} ,this code doesn't work any more

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is this:

```
    <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <databases>
      <database id="master" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.Database, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
          <obj type="Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)HistoryStorage, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <param connectionStringName="$(id)" />
            <EntryLifeTime>30.00:00:00</EntryLifeTime>
          </obj>
        </Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
        <Engines.HistoryEngine.SaveDotNetCallStack>false</Engines.HistoryEngine.SaveDotNetCallStack>
      </database>
    </databases>
    <search>
      <configuration>
        <indexes>
          <index id="newsArticles" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="folder">newsArticle</param>
            <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer" />
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <master type="Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler.Crawlers.AdvancedDatabaseCrawler,Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler">
                <Database>master</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/content/Data</Root>
                <IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields>
                <MonitorChanges>true</MonitorChanges>
                <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
                  <News>{EF11A8D0-D373-4A4B-90BA-16984D277612}</News>
                </include>
```

Now I have included the template id which I need my search index to search. When I build I can see that the items containing this specific template id exists.

Now to search:

```
try
        {
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
            Sitecore.Search.Index indx = SearchManager.GetIndex("newsArticles");
            using (IndexSearchContext searchContext = indx.CreateSearchContext())
            {
                var db = Sitecore.Context.Database;
                CombinedQuery query = new CombinedQuery();

                QueryBase catQuery = new FieldQuery("category", GuidsToSearchFor); //FieldName, FieldValue.
                SearchHits results = searchContext.Search(catQuery); //Searching the content items by fields.

                SearchResultCollection result = results.FetchResults(0, numOfArticles);
                RetrieveUrlListings(myItems, db, result, true);
            }
        }
```

Your result will contain the list of the items present in the index viewer.

Hope this helps! Check out this [link](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/get-latest-news-using-sitecore-advanceddatabasecrawler-lucene-index/) for more.

Comment: currently i'm using sitecore6.6, so searchContext.Search is deprecated.Still thanks very much for providing something I never seen before for me..~ ^^ cheers

Comment: Not a problem. I was just curious. How is searching done in 6.6 then?